# google app engine - ndb query to only get a few columns in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

In google app engine, is it possible to query the db to only get certain columns?

For example, I have a Model defined as follows:

```
class userData(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    emailAddress = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I usually query the db as follows:

```
userData.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('id') == "requiredId").fetch()
```

But this gives me results which contain id, name and email.

Now I would like to get only **id and name but not emailAddress**. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is called [projection query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries)

Example:

```
qry = Article.query()
articles = qry.fetch(20, projection=[Article.author, Article.tags])
for article in articles:
  # code here can use article.author, article.tags
  # but cannot use article.title
```

Your code:

```
class userData(ndb.Model):
    id = ndb.StringProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    emailAddress = ndb.StringProperty()

user = userData.query().filter(ndb.GenericProperty('id') ==  "requiredId")\
                       .fetch(projection=[userData.id, userData.name])
```

Though I need to quote from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries):

> Projection can be useful; if you only need two small properties each
> from several large entities, the fetch is more efficient since it gets
> and deserializes less data.

Think about the above when you use projection queries

P.S.

Also use CapWords convention for class names in python if you want to follow the [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Comment: Thank you @Jimmy Kane for the answer and I will follow PEP too.

Comment: Link changed to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries

Comment: Projections work great, but if the column e.g. is a long unindexed TextProperty or JsonProperty it will not work. I'm still wondering what is the best way to include such columns these in a subset select.